# Help pairing Lg Tone to Lubuntu (Blueman)

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, blueman

Problem: LG TONE FAIL TO PAIR WITH LUBUNTU ON LAPTOP

I have installed Blueman Bluetooth manager.
It is running properly.

I am attempting to pair my bluetooth headset, LG Tone, to the Blueman Bluetooth manager in Lubuntu on my Acer Aspire E11.

The bluetooth headset is switched ON, fully charged, and not paired to any other device, but it will not pair-up with the Blueman manager.

Anyone have a suggestion I could try?